# While running the application on Weblogic server getting this errors

Tags: java

> org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Module named
>   '_auto_generated_ear_' failed to deploy. See Error Log view for more
>   detail.   at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deployAutoGenerateEarApplication(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:852)
>     at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1452)
>     at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:944)
>     at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:735)
>     at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:584)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3182)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:355)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)
>   Contains: Module named '_auto_generated_ear_' failed to start.
>   Contains: weblogic.application.ModuleException:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: MultipartFilter: No temporary upload
>   directory found
>
> java.lang.Exception: Exception received from deployment driver. See
>   Error Log view for more detail.   at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.DeploymentProgressListener.watch(DeploymentProgressListener.java:193)
>     at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.startModule(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:1178)
>     at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deployAutoGenerateEarApplication(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:843)
>     at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1452)
>     at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:944)
>     at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:735)
>     at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:584)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3182)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:355)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)

Comment: "See Error Log view for more detail" - what does the error log say?

Answer (score 0):

According to the `javax.servlet.ServletException` you are getting, you are trying to upload to a directory that doesn't exist:

```
MultipartFilter: No temporary upload directory found.  Set a property named 'AVS.FILE_UPLOAD.TEMP_DIR' to a valid directory.
```

The solution is to either create the directory or point to a valid directory.

Comment: i have created a new directory and added into the properties file ...still i am getting same error. and the file is into client machine and i am doing the local setup for this.

Comment: Perhaps it is a files permissions issue. The code might not see the directory as you might be lacking permissions (either locally or on the server)

Comment: Probably, but it is hard to do from a distance :(